# GGplot and function not being found

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have been working on R shiny code and I have been having issues with updating data in it. And now that I have solved it I am having issues with the data being read the code for the creation of my plots.
I made a mini code with a simpler plot (a line graph) that is working:

```
new_data<-function(test1){#data prep
  test1$Date<-as.Date(test1$Date)
  test1<-arrange(test1,Date)
  test1$Growth<-as.numeric(test1$Growth)
  
  data_beef<-filter(test1,test1$Type=="BEEF")
  data_beef$Vphase<-paste0(data_beef$Variety,data_beef$Phase)
  data_beef_date<-filter(data_beef,data_beef$Growth!="NA")

  e<-data_beef_date$Week
  f<-data_beef_date$Growth
  g<-data_beef_date$Vphase
  return(data.frame(e,f,g))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
            plotOutput("plot1"),
            verbatimTextOutput("stats"))
    
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data<-reactiveFileReader(1000,session,"Crop Registration 2022.xlsx",readFunc=read_excel,sheet="CSV")
  df<-reactive({new_data(data())})

  test2<-reactive({filter(df(),df()[[1]]>18)})
  output$plot1<-renderPlot({p<-ggplot(test2(),aes(x=test2()[[1]],y=test2()[[2]],colour=test2()[[3]]))+geom_line()+
      xlab("Date")+ylab("Growth (cm)")+scale_color_hue(name="Variety",l=40)
  
  p})
  output$stats<-renderPrint({test2()})
  }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The weird part of this toy code is that the dataframe `df` has to be followed by `()` which I think is an issue when I try to bring this thinking to my larger more complicated plot creation. I will put down the relative code (since I have only been working on one of the 100+ plots). The more complicated plot is a boxplot with significant difference lines.

```
beefGrowthData<-function(dataIn){
  dataIn<-arrange(dataIn,Date)
  data_beef<-filter(dataIn,dataIn$Type=="BEEF")
  data_beef_growth<-filter(data_beef,data_beef$Growth!="NA")
  data_beef_growth$Vphase<-paste0(data_beef_growth$variety,"_",data_beef_growth$Phase)
  data_beef_growth$ID<-paste0(data_beef$Vphase,data_beef$Plant)
  e<-data_beef_growth$Week
  f<-data_beef_growth$Growth
  g<-data_beef_growth$Vphase
  h<-data_beef_growth$ID
  return(data.frame(e,f,g,h))
}
```

```
#I eventually want to remove this part to autoupdate the sliders but one problem at a time
df<-read_excel("Crop Registration 2022.xlsx",sheet="CSV")
data_beef<-filter(df,Type=="BEEF")
ui<-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Beef Boxplots",tabName="BeefBoxplots",icon=icon("cog", lib = "glyphicon"))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName ="BeefBoxplots",
              fluidRow(box(title="Growth",plotOutput("plot1",height = 500),width=8)
                       ,box(title = "Weeks",width = 4,sliderInput("slider1","Starting Week:",1,max(data_beef$Week),max(data_beef$Week)-6)))
)))
```

```
server <- function(input, output,session) { 
  data<-reactiveFileReader(1000,session,"Crop Registration 2022.xlsx",readFunc=read_excel,sheet="CSV")
  df2<-reactive({beefGrowthData(data())})
  

  #Beef-Growth
  output$plot1<-renderPlot({data_s<-filter(df2(), df2()[[1]]>input$slider1-1)
  bxp<-ggboxplot(data_s(),x="data_s()[[1]]",y="data_s()[[2]]",color="data_s()[[3]]",palette = "jco")+xlab("Week")+ylab("Growth (cm)")
  
  
  res.aov<-anova_test(data=data_s(),dv=data_s()[[2]],wid=data_s()[[4]],between=data_s()[[3]],within=data_s()[[1]])
  
  one.way<-data_s()%>%group_by(data_s()[[1]])%>%anova_test(dv=data_s()[[2]],wid=data_s()[[4]],between=data_s()[[3]])%>%get_anova_table()%>%adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni")
  
  pwc<-data_s()%>%group_by(data_s()[[1]])%>%pairwise_t_test(data_s()[[2]]~data_s()[[3]],p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
  
  
  pwc<-pwc%>%add_xy_position(x="data_s()[[1]]")
  
  growthplot<-bxp+stat_pvalue_manual(pwc,tip.length=0,hide.ns=TRUE)+labs(subtitle=get_test_label(res.aov,detailed = TRUE),caption = get_pwc_label(pwc))
  
  growthplot})
}
```

I get an error of `Error in data_s: could not find function "data_s"` I feel this has something to do with the `()` changing the nautre of the dataframe but my meager coding skills does not help me here. When I don't use the auto-updating data the plot creation works. I have seen code where a dataframes returned from a function do not have `()` afterwards but I am unable to get that to work.

I'm sorry for so much code in a question but I felt all of it was relavant to this problem I have encountered.

Comment: which line do you think defines a function called `data_s`

Comment: So if I was basing it off the test model which is working (`test2<-reactive(...)`) I would say `data_s<-filter(df2(), df2()[[1]]>input$slider1-1)` but judging by your tone it isn't defined anywhere

Comment: well youve defined `data` and `df2` but there is not a similar one for `data_s`. and you also use `filter` elsewhere but it is to subset a data frame `data_beef<-filter(df,Type=="BEEF")`, not to define a new function

Comment: How is `data_s<-filter(df2(), df2()[[1]]>input$slider1-1)` different from ` test2<-reactive({filter(df(),df()[[1]]>18)})` ? Is it because the former is located within the renderPlot and it should be outside and be reactive?

Comment: yes I think it should be reactive, presumably you want to change the slider input and have the data updated. as you have it, it will execute once and never change with the slider. the `{...}` inside of `renderPlot` does not render a plot either

Comment: I confirm `data_s` needs to be a `reactive`

Comment: Ok that is weird since the static data version of the plot renders a plot and the plot updates when I shift the slider. God I really have bitten off too much.

Comment: Yeah at this point when I put `data_s<-reactive({filter(df2(), df2()[[1]]>input$slider1-1)})` I get errors associated with not being able to find columns associated with `bxp<-ggboxplot(data_s(),x="data_s()[[1]]",y="data_s()[[2]]",color="data_s()[[3]]",palette = "jco")+xlab("Week")+ylab("Growth (cm)")` So yeah....one problem solved and more pop up